# How to extract the p-value for the slope from an ols object in R

Tags: r, regression

If I do

```
data(mtcars)
m1 <- lm(mpg ~ cyl, data= mtcars, x= TRUE, y= TRUE)
```

then I can extract the p-value for the slope using `summary(m1)$coefficients[2, 4]`.

But if I do

```
library(rms)
data(mtcars)
m2 <- ols(mpg ~ cyl, data= mtcars, x= TRUE, y= TRUE)
```

what do I need to do to extract the p-value for the slope?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the corresponding extractor function, but you need to call `summary.lm`:

```
> coef(summary.lm(m2))
          Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
Intercept 37.88458  2.0738436 18.267808 8.369155e-18
cyl       -2.87579  0.3224089 -8.919699 6.112687e-10
```