# How to get p.values of coefficients from ols() model of rms package in R

Tags: r, structure, regression, rms

I am running regression using mtcars data set and ols() function of rms package as follows:

```
> library(rms)
> mod_ols = ols(mpg~wt+qsec+am+hp+vs+drat+cyl, mtcars)                           
> 
> mod_ols

Linear Regression Model

ols(formula = mpg ~ wt + qsec + am + hp + vs + drat + cyl, data = mtcars)

                Model Likelihood     Discrimination    
                   Ratio Test           Indexes        
Obs       32    LR chi2     62.73    R2       0.859    
sigma 2.5703    d.f.            7    R2 adj   0.818    
d.f.      24    Pr(> chi2) 0.0000    g        6.519    

Residuals

    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.3615 -1.7407 -0.2537  1.0893  4.5929 

          Coef    S.E.    t     Pr(>|t|)
Intercept 15.7714 16.5491  0.95 0.3501  
wt        -3.0826  1.0888 -2.83 0.0092  
qsec       0.7426  0.6632  1.12 0.2739  
am         2.5945  1.8802  1.38 0.1803  
hp        -0.0182  0.0162 -1.12 0.2728  
vs         0.2321  2.0291  0.11 0.9099  
drat       0.6387  1.5186  0.42 0.6778  
cyl        0.0309  0.9091  0.03 0.9732
```

The structure of model produced is as follows:

```
> str(mod_ols)
List of 18
 $ coefficients     : Named num [1:8] 15.7714 -3.0826 0.7426 2.5945 -0.0182 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:8] "Intercept" "wt" "qsec" "am" ...
 $ residuals        : Named num [1:32] -2.193 -1.823 -3.362 0.714 1.81 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:32] "Mazda RX4" "Mazda RX4 Wag" "Datsun 710" "Hornet 4 Drive" ...
 $ effects          : Named num [1:32] -113.65 -29.12 -9.1 5.12 3.04 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:32] "Intercept" "wt" "qsec" "am" ...
 $ rank             : int 8
 $ fitted.values    : Named num [1:32] 23.2 22.8 26.2 20.7 16.9 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:32] "Mazda RX4" "Mazda RX4 Wag" "Datsun 710" "Hornet 4 Drive" ...
 $ assign           :List of 7
  ..$ wt  : int 2
  ..$ qsec: int 3
  ..$ am  : int 4
  ..$ hp  : int 5
  ..$ vs  : int 6
  ..$ drat: int 7
  ..$ cyl : int 8
 $ qr               :List of 5
  ..$ qr   : num [1:32, 1:8] -5.657 0.177 0.177 0.177 0.177 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:32] "Mazda RX4" "Mazda RX4 Wag" "Datsun 710" "Hornet 4 Drive" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:8] "Intercept" "wt" "qsec" "am" ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "assign")= int [1:8] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
  ..$ qraux: num [1:8] 1.18 1.05 1.08 1.18 1.03 ...
  ..$ pivot: int [1:8] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
  ..$ tol  : num 0.0000001
  ..$ rank : int 8
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "qr"
 $ df.residual      : int 24
 $ var              : num [1:8, 1:8] 273.872 3.919 -9.225 -13.12 -0.054 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:8] "Intercept" "wt" "qsec" "am" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:8] "Intercept" "wt" "qsec" "am" ...
 $ stats            : Named num [1:6] 32 62.733 7 0.859 6.519 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:6] "n" "Model L.R." "d.f." "R2" ...
 $ linear.predictors: Named num [1:32] 23.2 22.8 26.2 20.7 16.9 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:32] "Mazda RX4" "Mazda RX4 Wag" "Datsun 710" "Hornet 4 Drive" ...
 $ call             : language ols(formula = mpg ~ wt + qsec + am + hp + vs + drat + cyl, data = mtcars)
 $ terms            :Classes 'terms', 'formula' length 3 mpg ~ wt + qsec + am + hp + vs + drat + cyl
  .. ..- attr(*, "variables")= language list(mpg, wt, qsec, am, hp, vs, drat, cyl)
  .. ..- attr(*, "factors")= int [1:8, 1:7] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:8] "mpg" "wt" "qsec" "am" ...
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:7] "wt" "qsec" "am" "hp" ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "term.labels")= chr [1:7] "wt" "qsec" "am" "hp" ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "order")= int [1:7] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  .. ..- attr(*, "intercept")= num 1
  .. ..- attr(*, "response")= int 1
  .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
  .. ..- attr(*, "predvars")= language list(mpg, wt, qsec, am, hp, vs, drat, cyl)
  .. ..- attr(*, "dataClasses")= Named chr [1:8] "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:8] "mpg" "wt" "qsec" "am" ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "formula")=Class 'formula' length 3 mpg ~ wt + qsec + am + hp + vs + drat + cyl
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
 $ Design           :List of 11
  ..$ name        : chr [1:7] "wt" "qsec" "am" "hp" ...
  ..$ label       : chr [1:7] "wt" "qsec" "am" "hp" ...
  ..$ units       : Named chr [1:7] "" "" "" "" ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:7] "wt" "qsec" "am" "hp" ...
  ..$ colnames    : chr [1:7] "wt" "qsec" "am" "hp" ...
  ..$ assume      : chr [1:7] "asis" "asis" "asis" "asis" ...
  ..$ assume.code : int [1:7] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  ..$ parms       : list()
  ..$ limits      : list()
  ..$ values      : list()
  ..$ nonlinear   :List of 7
  .. ..$ wt  : logi FALSE
  .. ..$ qsec: logi FALSE
  .. ..$ am  : logi FALSE
  .. ..$ hp  : logi FALSE
  .. ..$ vs  : logi FALSE
  .. ..$ drat: logi FALSE
  .. ..$ cyl : logi FALSE
  ..$ interactions: list()
 $ non.slopes       : num 1
 $ na.action        : NULL
 $ scale.pred       : chr "mpg"
 $ fail             : logi FALSE
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "ols" "rms" "lm"
>
```

However, I am not able to find the p.values in mod_ols structure. How can I get P values of coefficients from models produced by ols() function of rms package? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279931/how-to-extract-the-p-value-for-the-slope-from-an-ols-object-in-r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `summary.lm`:

```
summary.lm(mod_ols)$coefficients[ , "Pr(>|t|)"]
#  Intercept          wt        qsec          am          hp          vs 
#0.350087341 0.009234825 0.273857810 0.180345204 0.272787068 0.909889126 
#       drat         cyl 
#0.677806300 0.973163043
```

Each of the following lines will do the trick, as well:

```
summary.lm(mod_ols)$coefficients[ , 4] 
coef(summary.lm(mod_ols))[ , 4]
coef(summary.lm(mod_ols))[ , "Pr(>|t|)"]
```

Comment: Why does `summary` get hijacked for `ols`?

Comment: @JesseKnight `summary` is a "generic function," and the output depends on the class of the input object.  If you call `summary` on the `mod_ols` object, then under the hood `summary.rms`, a function from the `rms` package, gets called.

If you want to learn more about that general topic and how it works, you can search for "R" and terms like "S3", "generic functions", "method distpatch", and "OOP."